# Casting Null Object into Integer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to understand the following code. Line number 2 outputs **null** while line 3 throws **NullPointerException**. What am I missing ? Theoretically it should work.

```
public static void main(String []args){

  1  Object[] obj = {null}; 
  2  System.out.println((Integer)obj[0]);  //Output null

  3  Integer n = obj[0] == null ? (Integer)obj[0] : 1; //NullPointerException
  4  System.out.println(n);
 }
```

Comment: The use of an array and a cast to Integer adds extra noise to the code in terms of asking about the behaviour: `Integer num = null;` would be easier, and semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the rules defined in the JLS, the type of the ternary conditional operator

```
null ? (Integer)obj[0] : 1;
```

is `int`, not `Integer`.

Hence, when the result of this expression is `(Integer)obj[0]`, the `Integer` is unboxed to `int`, and you get `NullPointerException`.

See [JLS 15.25. Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), Table 15.25-A. :

Since your second operand is `Integer` and your third operand is `int`, the conditional expression type is `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The key concept here is *[binary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)*.

When you supply an operator with operands of different types, the operands have to be are converted to be compatible with one another. The conditional operator's rules for this conversion are reasonably complicated; but when the operands are of differing types, and are convertible to numbers, binary numeric promotion is applied.

In the case of supplying one boxed and one primitive operand, the effect of binary numeric promotion is to attempt to unbox the boxed operand, *not* to box the primitive operand.

You get can observe binary numeric promotion with other multi-operand operators, for example `+`:

```
System.out.println(1 + (Integer) null); // NullPointerException!
```

With the conditional operator, you would not get a NPE if you explicitly box the 1, because the operands are then not of differing types:

```
Integer n = obj[0] == null ? (Integer)obj[0] : Integer.valueOf(1);
```

Comment: Nicely explains **why** the code behaves like that. Actually, the better answer imho.